# Event Sourcing - Aggregate modeling

Tags: event-sourcing

Two questions
1) How to model aggregate and reference between them
2) How to organise/store events so that they can be retrieved efficiently

Take this typical use case as example, we have Order and LineItem (they are an aggregate, Order is the aggregate root), and Product aggregate.
As LineItem needs to know which Product, so there are two options 1) LineItem has direct reference to Product aggregate (which seems not a best practice, as it violate the idea of aggregate being a consistence boundary because we can update Product aggregate directly from Order aggregate) 2) then LineItem only has ProductId.

It looks like 2nd option is the way to go...What do you think here?

However, another problem arises which is about building a Order read/view model. In this Order view model, it needs to know which Products are in Order (i.e. ProductId, Type, etc.). The typical use case is reporting, and CommandHandler also can use this Product object to perform logic such as whether there are too many particular products, etc. In order to do it, given the fact that those data are in two separate aggregate, then we need 1+ database roundtrips. As we are using events to build model, so the pseudo code looks like below
1) for a given order id (guid, order aggregate id), we load all the events for it; -- 1st database access
2) then build a Order aggregate, then we know which ProductId are referenced in Order;
3) for the list of ProductIds, we load all events for it; -- 2nd database access

If we build a really big graph of objects (a lot of different aggregates), then this may end up with a few more database access (each of which is slow)...What's your idea in here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Take this typical use case as example, we have Order and LineItem (they are an aggregate, Order is the aggregate root), and Product aggregate.

The Order aggregate makes sense the way you have described it.  "Product aggregate" is more suspicious; do you ask the model if the product is allowed to change, or are you telling the model that the product has changed?

If Product can change without first consulting with the order, then the LineItem must *not* include the product.  A reference to the product (aka the ProductId) is ok.

> If we build a really big graph of objects (a lot of different aggregates), then this may end up with a few more database access (each of which is slow)...What's your idea in here?

For reads, reports, and the like -- where you aren't going to be adding new events to the history -- one possible answer is to do the slow work in advance.  An asynchronous process listens for writes in the event store, and then publishes those events to a bus.  Subscribers build new versions of the reports when new events are observed, and cache the results.  (search keyword: [cqrs](/questions/tagged/cqrs))

When a client asks for a report, you give them one out of the cache.  All the work is done, so it's very quick.

For command handlers, the answer is more complicated.  Business rules are supposed to be in the domain model, so having the command handler try to validate the command (as opposed to the domain model) is a bit broken.

The command handler can load the products to see what the state might look like, and pass that information to the aggregate with the command data, but it's not clear that's a good idea -- if the client is going to send a command to be run, and you need to flesh out the Order command with Product data, why not instead have the command add the product data to the command directly, and skip the middle man.

> CommandHandler also can use this Product object to perform logic such as whether there are too many particular products, etc.

This example is a bit vague, but taking a guess: you are thinking about cases where you prevent an order from being placed if the available inventory is insufficient to fulfill the order.

For real world inventory - a physical book in a warehouse - that's probably the wrong approach to take.  First, the model itself is wrong; if you want to know how much product is in the warehouse, you should be querying the warehouse, not the product.  Second, a physical warehouse is not constrained by your model -- calling the addProduct method on a warehouse aggregate doesn't cause the product to magically appear there.

Third, it probably doesn't match very well with what your domain experts want anyway.  If the model says that the warehouse doesn't have enough product, do you think the stake holders want the system to

1. tell the shopper to buy the product somewhere else, or...
2. accept the order, and contact the supplier for a new delivery.

Hint: when in doubt, carefully review how amazon.com does it.